# How do i change my diet so I can workout in the morning

Tags: diet, workout, nutrition, food

A few months ago I joined the gym and I went to the gym's nutritionist to prepare a suitable diet, but she prepared in a way so that I workout during the afternoon. But now my schedule changed and I can only go to the gym in the morning about 10 AM. How should I change my diet? I don't want to spend money on another consultation just to move some things around. This is my diet:

9 AM:
-Glass of milk or an egg
-70g of whole grain bread with a slice of cheese
-Fruit

11:30 AM:
- 1 tuna can
- Egg white omelet with a slice of turkey ham
- Liquid yougurt

13:30 PM:
-Half a plate of low fat meat or fish
- 1/4 a plate of rice/sweet potato
-1/4 a plate of stewed vegetables or raw carrot
-fruit

17:00 pm:
- 1 Egg
- Corn Flakes
-Fruit

18:30-19:45:
-Gym

20:30 pm:
- The same as 13:30 pm

21:30:
- Glass of milk
-3 Rice cookies

Comment: I don’t understand why it needs to be changed, what is the problem?

Comment: Because I dont think I should drink milk and eat cheese right before training and also feel like meal it is not enough "fuel"

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it? Nutrition doesn't have to be set in stone, as long as you meet the macros and your calorie target, it can vary.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is probably give it a couple of weeks and see how you get on.

When I used to train in the morning (0600 - 0700), I'd typically get up, have a cup of black coffee and a banana, then head out the door. I'd train for about an hour, then have a decent breakfast that I'd previously prepared once I got into the office (breakfast was usually potatoes with smoked mackerel).

There are a couple of things to bear in mind when training in the morning. First, depending on the intensity of your training, you may find that eating before training makes you feel a bit sick (it's due to your body moving blood from your digestive tract into your muscles to fuel your training, meaning it can't digest the food in your stomach, so it tries to get rid of it). If this happens, either leave more time between breakfast and training (eat earlier) or eat less / eat more easily digestible food.

Second is dehydration. You tend to lose a lot of water from your body overnight through breathing, so make sure you drink enough before and during training (just not so much that it's slopping around in your stomach).

Whatever you do, you should understand that it may take a little time for your body to adapt to training at a different time of day, so give it a few sessions before you dramatically change anything.

Answer (score -1):

From your diet it looks like you aim for a lean physique, or to lower body fat.

In such case I would recommend to eat nothing at all before the 10 AM gym. And wait as long as possible after the gym before you eat. This will put you in the longest possible intermittent fast. You will likely feel, after a few days of adjustment, that you are much more energetic by postponing the meals.

Comment: Why he/she do intermittent fasting? There is nothing suggesting that it would be beneficial here.

Comment: I realize intermittent fasting is one of the latest "big things" in exercise and dieting, but this answer would be greatly improved with some sources backing up why it would be beneficial.

Comment: @JustSnilloc OP doesn't specify a fitness goal, so I qualified my answer with an assumed goal, for which IF is very beneficial.

Comment: Intermittent Fasting is simply about timing your meals. It has no unique health benefits. Does it work for some people? Of course, but it doesn’t work for everyone because not everyone finds such a schedule as being complimentary or sustainable for their life.

Comment: @JustSnilloc I've done IF for years. It's a very comfortable and easy way to cut calories, because you don't have to go to bed hungry and you can feast every day, just not all the day. It also boosts your energy for normal activity until you start eating. No it may not have unique health benefits in principle, but if it makes you able to stay on a reduced calorie program you otherwise wouldn't sustain, then it will in effect give a unique health effect. And it does make you less tired during the fasting-hours, which is a practical benefit anyway.